# Save recorded video in documents folder

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to save a movie in the documents folder right after i record it.

This is my code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {



    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"path from image picker: %@", moviePath);

    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@",documentsDir);

    [fileManager moveItemAtPath:moviePath toPath:documentsDir error:nil];

    NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir
                                                  error:nil];

    for (id object in files) {
        NSLog(@"%@",object);
    }
}
```

As you probably guessed, it doesn't work.

The first log says: path from image picker: /private/var/mobile/Applications/6630FBD3-1212-4ED0-BC3B-0C23AEEFB267/tmp/capture-T0x1e575330.tmp.SQQ2C5/capturedvideo.MOV

The seconds log says: /var/mobile/Applications/6630FBD3-1212-4ED0-BC3B-0C23AEEFB267/Documents

Anyone has any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Check my answer for saving video into directory I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code, when you save something, the file should have a filename and extension of that file. In your code the destination save path is just the document directory. That is wrong. using [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename.extension] will give you the correct destination filePath, [moviePath lastPathComponent] returns the filename+extension of the selected file.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"path from image picker: %@", moviePath);

    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[moviePath lastPathComponent]];

    NSLog(@"%@",savePath);

    [fileManager moveItemAtPath:moviePath toPath:savePath error:nil];

    NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir
                                                      error:nil];

    for (id object in files) {
        NSLog(@"%@",object);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added few lines to the answer, go through them. Tell me if you want more explanation,  hope you will mark it as the answer